# GRUB: Sending orders to a GRUB in another partition

Tags: grub2

Let's supose I have a **remote managed** computer having this **partitions structure**:

```
/dev/sda1   LinuxA      --> GRUB installed on /dev/sda
/dev/sda2   LinuxB
/dev/sda3   Windows
```

**GRUB installed on LinuxA** has all the three operating systems on the GRUB menu.

If I boot into LinuxA and I do:

```
# grub-reboot 1
# reboot
```

then my computer boot into LinuxB, as expected.
And now, I would like to boot into Windows.
As long as the computer is remotely managed, the best way I know is:

```
# reboot
```

then I boot into LinuxA again, and:

```
# grub-reboot 2
# reboot
```

so I will finally boot into Windows.

I assume that, from Windows, I have no chance to change this, but at least when I am running LinuxB, isn't there a way to **directly order booting** into the third option (Windows) of GRUB?

I know I can install GRUB from LinuxB, but it seems a bit awkward to do things that way.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but it might work.

Currently you have two Linuxes installed in two different partitions each having their own `/boot` partition. Below setup might work if both the Linuxes are of the same flavour or if they both have the same `grub` version.

1. Create a separate partition for `/boot` which will be used by both the Linuxes i.e `/boot` is common for both.
2. To make `/boot` common for both Linux first install Windows then Linux-A and then install Linux-B. While installing Linux-B dont allow the OS installer to format the partition so that the kernel images and initramfs of Linux-A will be intact.
3. After Windows, Linux-A and Linux-B are installed now the `/boot` partition will contain the grub configuration for all the three operating systems and initramfs and kernel images of Linux-A and Linux-B.
4. Now as the `/boot` partition is common for both Linux-A and Linux-B you can run `grub-reboot` from both the operating systems so that the temporary boot order gets changed while rebooting.

You might first need to test this in a different setup and then proceed with your actual system.

AS the machine is remotely managed, you can also try using/setting up [console servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_server#Console_server) for this.

Comment: Sharing `/boot` seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I don't foresee any issues if, both Linux has the same version of Grub with properly configured `grub.cfg`.